# Calculating the return money in a function and returning a dictionary with the money values as keys and amount as values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I got this function so far, but its returning also the values I don´t need.

Code:

```py
 COINS = (0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0)
 BANK_NOTES = (5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0, 200.0, 500.0)

 def get_return_money (payment_amount,total_price):
     return_money = payment_amount - total_price
     change_money_dict = {}
     for notes_coins in sorted(BANK_NOTES + COINS, reverse = True):
         change_money_dict[notes_coins], return_money = divmod(return_money, notes_coins)
     return change_money_dict
```

```
get_return_money(1000, 370.99)
Output: {500.0: 1.0, 200.0: 0.0, 100.0: 1.0, 50.0: 0.0, 20.0: 1.0, 10.0: 0.0, 5.0: 1.0, 2.0: 2.0, 1.0: 0.0, 0.5: 0.0, 0.2: 0.0, 0.1: 0.0, 0.05: 0.0, 0.02: 0.0, 0.01: 0.0}
```

What conditions must be true to return only the used values ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
COINS = (0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0)
BANK_NOTES = (5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0, 200.0, 500.0)

def get_return_money (payment_amount,total_price):
    return_money = payment_amount - total_price
    change_money_dict = {}
    for notes_coins in sorted(BANK_NOTES + COINS, reverse = True):
     change_money_dict[notes_coins], return_money = divmod(return_money, notes_coins)
     return_money = round(return_money,2)

    new_dict = {k:v for k,v in change_money_dict.items() if v != 0.0}    
    return new_dict
```

Comment: Why the new dict ?

Comment: if you want same dict. you can write same dict.

Comment: If it works, check it as the answer plz. Hit the check between the two arrows.

Comment: works fine, thanks. How would you do it without that comprehension ?

Comment: with my input : `get_return_money(1000, 370.99)` the right output should be in sum 629.01

Comment: you can use `round` function to get right output. check edit of my answer.